# Reactive Stream: merge flux data into for loop

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I have the `readEvents` function witch returns an event flux, in the below code i tried to merge all the events, so i used `mergeWith`, but the `allEventFlux` always returns empty

```
    val ids = repository.findIds().map { it.ekycId }
    val allEventFlux = Flux.empty<Event>()
    for (id in ids) {
        val events: Flux<Event> = eventStore.readEvents(id)
        allEventFlux.mergeWith(events)
    }
```

Comment: to merge  function VAL witch the event flux returns an i

Comment: Did you try using `Flux.merge(Iterable)` and collecting the event flux instances into a collection first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried :

```java
Flux.fromIterable(repository.findIds())
    .map { it.ekycId }
    .flatMap { id -> eventStore.readEvents(id) }
```

P.S : your current example cannot work, because "merge" does **not** merge *in-place*. It creates a new instance, that must be set to a variable, so as a minimum, you should modify you example as follow:

```java
val eventFlux = ids.fold(Flux.empty<Event>()) { all, id -> all.mergeWith(eventStore.readEvents(id)) }
```